# What's the next pattern in the sequence?

Tags: pattern

there. I came across this puzzle in a primary school booklet for selective high school exams in Australia. Please help me find out the next pattern to appear in the sequence, as shown in the picture below. Thank you very much!
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is

> 4th, because each of the three patterns in the question contains exactly four lines, and only the 4th option in the answer has four lines.

Comment: Exactly my logic. I doubt whether there are other patterns beside this...

Comment: Thank you, SamRoy and WhatsUp. I think that your logic is reasonable. Let's also  to see how others think about it.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be

> 3, since each figure must have an intersection of lines.

Answer (score 1):

> 3. Because there are $0,1,2$ closed and equal shapes in each picture.

Comment: Why not 2? Both 2 and 3 has 3 closed areas. @JMP

Comment: The 3 shapes are different in pic 2. @SamRoy

Comment: Ah.. That's correct. However, to say "equal" space, there is only 1 pattern to refer to, namely the 3rd one in question as for the first two, 0 or 1 shapes' equality does not mean anything. That's my understanding @JMP

Comment: Both 0 and 1 shapes are trivially equal. @SamRoy

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

> 4, because they are all composed from 4 straight lines.